# JavaScript: Right Way to Perform More than One REST Call One after Another

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I need to perform three REST calls one after another... and reading the documentation I've understood that to chain them I've to use either `pipi` or `then` (which is an alias of `pipe`). I'm quite new to `JavaScript` and I'm wondering whether the following code snippet is the correct way to go:

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9000/auth";
var appId = this.appId
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: baseUrl + "/apps/" + appId + "/apikey"
}).then(function(data) {
  log("apiKey: " + data.apiKey);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ principal: appId, secret: data.apiKey }),
    url: baseUrl + "/apps/credentials",
    contentType: "application/json"  
  }).then(function(data) {
    log("token: " + data.token);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Token " + this.value },
      url: baseUrl + "/users/credentials"
    }).then(function(data) {
      log("tokeType: " + data.token.header.typ.split('/')[1]);
      log("exp: " + data.token.claims.exp);
    })
  })
});
```

As you can see, each call needs the data returned by the previous call. Any suggestion for improvement is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), you'll get a callback whether the ajax call succeeded or failed, which may not be ideal as you're relying on it being successful. [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) is the one you want if you only want the callback on success (that, or the `success` parameter to [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)).

Other than that, it's fine.